# Agora Detect Screen Share Stream on Audience Side

Tags: sdk, webrtc, agora.io

Does anybody know how to detect stream whether its a Screen Share or Webcam on the audience/remote Side ?

On the host side, I am able to detect but not on the audience side

I want to display screen shared remote stream in another part of the web page and webcam stream on another

Comment: Did you get the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

this is currently not possible with the RTC SDK. You need to use [the RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_web?platform=Web) in tandem with our RTC SDK to achieve this. RTM SDK will serve as a data signaling layer for the RTC.

For ease of use, you can [create an RTM channel](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmclient.html#createchannel) with the same name as the RTC channel.

When you start screen share, you can [signal everybody on the channel](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmchannel.html#sendmessage) to let them know which is the screen sharing stream.

Comment: And if a user enters the channel after the screen share has started?

Answer (score 0):

Screen share and video will come in as just video on the remote side with a callback. If you want to detect screen share vs. regular video that you need to develop some app logic on your side. For example, the screen share UID would be an integer only from 10000 to 11000 (depending on your usage, you could raise or lower this) so you know if the number comes from that range it is a screen share.