# Web Agora.io Find Stream Type is Share Screen

Tags: c#, agora.io

I am using c# with jquery.
When call "stream-added"/"stream-subscribed" i am unable to find that stream type is  "video"  or "share screen".

I follow "https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#addtrack" document to find track video.
I tried getVideoTrack() to get track but it always return me below.

```
MediaStreamTrack
contentHint: ""
enabled: true
id: "v0"
kind: "video"
label: "v0"
muted: false
onended: null
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
```

If any one have solution please share me . Thanks

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787895/agora-detect-screen-share-stream-on-audience-side/62871858#62871858

Comment: @vineethsrini there is no solution in your comment..

Comment: It seems that there is no way to detect it, you have to use something else to share the information with the audience that Stream X is the one sharing the screen. Agora has a messaging API called RTM and that's what the link suggests using it. Not ideal but at least there is a way out.